# How can I stop divs getting pushed down?

Tags: css, html, layout

I am trying to figure out how to get divs that I want on the same line to stay there, rather than getting pushed below when the screen is resized.

For example, I have a sidebar and a main body on all the pages in my website that I will give a defined width. They will sit directly next to each other, with the same height.

Sidebar CSS

```
#sidebar {

    width: 380px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    float: left;    
    background: #cee7f7;
    padding: 1%;

}
```

Body CSS

```
.container {
     width: 1125px; 
     margin-right: 10%; 
     float:right; 
     background: #fff; 
     padding: 1%;
}
```

You can see an example at [www.dweeman.com/eb/sitetemplate.html](http://www.dweeman.com/eb/sitetemplate.html) (Ignore the bad design).

Basically what I want is for all my divs (logo, phone, sidebar, body, footer etc) to all remain in their respective positions regardless of the screen size, yet with defined sizes. Does this have something to do with the `position` property?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Also how would I best describe this for the title of my question?)

Comment: You don't have media queries or viewport tag so it's because of the fluid structure. If you set the wrappers with static width and height, they'll stay in place when screen is resized.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS. What are media queries and viewport tags? And what are the wrappers I'm defining?

Comment: Well you can google to learn about media queries and viewport tag, but that's irrelevant here. Fluid structure means width/height is set relative to the outer wrap (div or any other element, body tag in case there's no other outer wrap). For instance your header's width is set to 80%. You can either set that to static width or specify minimum width as LoneChaos stated.

Comment: Okay I think I am getting it now. If you check out the website now I've made it a lot neater and work better, but I'm still missing something that gets the sidebar and body on the same line. I feel like it's really obvious and I'm just missing it

Comment: Do you want it this way? http://prntscr.com/2qx1pi
For that, replace min-wdith with max-width and float it left. Then set replace min-wdith with max-width for container, set it to some other static value, keep it floating right.

Comment: Yeah that screenshot is what I want it to look like. I've set those values, and they are on the same line now. The problem is, on one width (1980x1020) they are on the same line, but if I make my window smaller, eventually the container gets pushed below the sidebar. I'm trying to get it so once it gets to that point, instead of going below, it just starts to disappear out of the side of the window.

Comment: Okay, set clear:both for "main-content", then set max-wdith for "side-bar" 35% and 60% for "container". That should take of it.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be working well for the main-content area. But what I'm trying to figure out is how to get a div, lets take for example my navigation bar, to not push it's content down when it gets to a certain width. I want it so that when it gets to that width, instead of the content getting squeezed down, it stays on the same line and eventually starts to disappear out of the window.

Comment: For that, set definitive width and height for #navigation (not max-width, max-height) and add clear:both to it as well, then change display property to inline-block for #ddmenu http://prntscr.com/2qxqn1

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you very much for your help here. Only problem I have now is the phone still pushes on top of the logo, even though I have clear: both. Shouldn't that make their floats not overlap each other?

Comment: Same logic, make things static there. Set static width to header, #logo and #phone. Make sure you leave enough room for them to fit in there.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working. The header is simply 100%, with a 50px padding top, left and right, so does it's width need to be defined?
I'm trying to get them like the navigation bar, so they remain completely static, and disappear after a certain width.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify static width (not static position property). For instance, try width: 1000px; for header.

Comment: Okay wonderful, so a static width is essential. I really appreciate all your help, I've learnt a lot. Sorry I didn't have enough reputation to take this into a chat.

Comment: Not a problem. Have a good day ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the **min-width** and **min-height** of the **divs** if you want them to stay a specific size regardless of the screen size.